# What did Rivka tell her mother - Breishit 24:28?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-chaye-sara

Some context:

Eliezer probes Rivka's family identity and asks for a place to lodge. Rivka answers. Verse 27 begins with the word ויאמר (He said) as opposed to more specifically  ויאמר אליה (He said to her). It's unclear whether he was talking aloud to himself, or Rivka heard Eliezer say the blessing to G-d.

So, in verse 28, it says that she told her mother's house (family?) כדברים האלה - "**Like** these things". I assume that's what the extra כ implies, that she didn't repeat the exact words.

Even with this, what did Rivka relay? It seems clear that she relayed that there was a man standing outside who requested food and lodging. But, did she relay anything from Eliezer's blessing? Did she hear that? Or is it possible that the verse containing the blessing is out of chronological order?

None of the *Mikra'ot Gedolot* commentaries focus on this.

Answer (score 2):

I did not see any of the classic Mefarshim dealing with the Vayomer in Passuk 27.

A number of the Mefarshim [here](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Bereshit/24.28#e0n7) deal with what Rivkah told her family:

Ralbag says she told her mother (everything) the servant had told her, and showed her what he had given her:

> והגידה לבית אִמָּהּ כדברים האלה אשר דיבר אליה עבד אברהם, והראת אותה מה שנתן לה

RDZ Hoffman seems to say (not 100% sure, perhaps he means what he was saying now, as in the previous Passuk, which would be what you are looking for) that she said the basics of what the Pesukim continue to say that she said (see Passuk 30):

> כדברים האלה – דהיינו מה שסופר זה עתה.

Radak says here that she told them the whole story, more or less, just with slight changes in the wording:

> כדברים האלה – כענין הדברים האלה פחות מהם או יותר מהם או שנוי מלות כי כן דרך המספר.

Note that in that Passuk (30), Radak comments that Lavan had run out because Rivkah had told them that the man had come looking for a wife for his master's son.

> וכשמעו את דברי אחתו – נראה כי האיש דבר אליה ענין באו העיר לקחת אשה לבן אדניו, זהו שאמרה כה דבר אלי האיש.

From the less well-known commentaries, [Yashar](https://books.google.ca/books?id=j_FuC1T5nzwC&pg=PT6&dq=%22%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9D%22%20%22%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7%20%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9C%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) (YS Reggio) suggests that she overheard the comments of the servant in the previous verse, as you suggested.  I'm sure there are others as well.